# Drop rows containing a values based on a list in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

This is what my data looks like:

```
code_lst = [aa, del, sw]


| code  | name         | destination 
|------ |------------- |--------
| aa    | american air | jfk
| del   | delta        | mia
| aa    | american air | lax
| sw    | southwest    | ord
| sw    | southwest    | jfk
| spi   | spirit       | jfk
```

I want to drop rows that have a destination of `jfk` only if the code is in the `code_lst`.

```
| code  | name         | destination 
|------ |------------- |--------
| del   | delta        | mia
| aa    | american air | lax
| sw    | southwest    | ord
| spi   | spirit       | jfk
```

How would I achieve this in Pyspark?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a filtering condition in conjunction with [isin](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.isin.html) to match values within your `code_lst`

```
input_str = """
| aa    | american air | jfk
| del   | delta        | mia
| aa    | american air | lax
| sw    | southwest    | ord
| sw    | southwest    | jfk
| spi   | spirit       | jfk
""".split("|")

input_values = list(map(lambda x:x.strip(),input_str))[1:]

code = input_values[::3]
name = input_values[1::3]
destination = input_values[2::3]


input_list = [(x,y,z) for x,y,z in zip(code,name,destination)]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list,['code','name','destination'])

sparkDF.show()

+----+------------+-----------+
|code|        name|destination|
+----+------------+-----------+
|  aa|american air|        jfk|
| del|       delta|        mia|
|  aa|american air|        lax|
|  sw|   southwest|        ord|
|  sw|   southwest|        jfk|
| spi|      spirit|        jfk|
+----+------------+-----------+
```

## Filtering

```
code_lst = ["aa", "del", "sw"]

filter_condn = ~(
                (F.col('destination') == "jfk")
              & (F.col('code').isin(code_lst))
            )

sparkDF.filter(filter_condn).show()

+----+------------+-----------+
|code|        name|destination|
+----+------------+-----------+
| del|       delta|        mia|
|  aa|american air|        lax|
|  sw|   southwest|        ord|
| spi|      spirit|        jfk|
+----+------------+-----------+
```

**Note - I have used `not (~)` against the filter condition , to only fetch rows not matching the required condition**

Comment: I liked the use of `~` operator.